# Alphabetical comparator Javascript using localeCompare

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to create a comparator that returns true or false for is greater, less than and equal to. I've found the localeCompare function which compares 2 strings and returns 1,0 or -1. I tried returning true or false as its shown below but this way is not working. How can this work?

```
let ComparatorAlphabetical = (item) => {
    let _isGreaterThan = if(item.localeCompare(item2) == 1) => true;
    let _isLessThan = if(item.localeCompare(item2) == -1) => false;
    let _isEqualTo = if(item.localeCompare(item2) == 0) => false;

    return {
        isGreaterThan: _isGreaterThan,
        isLessThan: _isLessThan,
        isEqualTo: _isEqualTo
    }
}
```

This comparator is going to be used to create a sortingfunction

```
let createSortFunc = (comparator) => (ascending) => {
    let condition = ascending ? (comparator(item).isGreaterThan(item2)) : (comparator(item).isLessThan(item2));

    return (array => array.sort(({ shortName: item1 }, { shortName: item2 }) => (!comparator(item1).isEqualTo(item2)) ?
        (condition ? 1 : -1) :
        0));
}
```

Comment: You can't have `if` statement of the right hand side of assignment expression. And also what is `item2`

Comment: Also no need `let _isGreaterThan = item.localeCompare(item2) == 1;`

Comment: You will get a better solution if you could explain your needs with example input and expected output.

Comment: how about that: `let _isGreaterThan = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == 1;`
`let _isLessThan = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == -1;` `let _isEqualTo = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == 0;` ?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55933211/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and give us a [mcve]

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? You seem to be massively overcomplicating things.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Instead of asking us to fix your attempted solution, please post the inputs, expected output with a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
let ComparatorAlphabetical = (item) => {
   let _isGreaterThan = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == 1; 
   let _isLessThan = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == -1; 
   let _isEqualTo = (i) => item.localeCompare(i) == 0;

    return {
        isGreaterThan: _isGreaterThan,
        isLessThan: _isLessThan,
        isEqualTo: _isEqualTo
    }
}
```

but i agree with James Coyle, you seem to be overcomplicating things.

Comment: I Think you and James are right im overcomplicating things. This is working but i think im rethinking the whole thing. Thanks everyone

Comment: @marijn are you trying to sort an array based on alphabetical order and the direction is based on `ascending` boolean?

Comment: @marijn if working can you accept the answer? And yeah I think it would be good to rethink a bit your design ;)

Comment: @adiga yes that is what im trying

Comment: @Romain I wasn't able to yet because of the countdown but its done now

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to sort the array based on `ascending` boolean, you can create a `multiplier` value and set it to 1 or -1. Then simply multiply it to the value returned by `localeCompare`:

```js
let input = [{ shortName: 'b' }, { shortName: 'a' }, { shortName: 'Z' }]

function sort(array, ascending) {
  const mutiplier = ascending ? 1 : -1;
  return array.sort((a, b) => mutiplier * a.shortName.localeCompare(b.shortName))
}

console.log(sort(input, true)) // ascending 
console.log(sort(input, false)) // descending
```